# c# - Add to string[] member

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, visual-studio

I have a List<string[]> called lst:

```
[0] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI"
[1] "JKL" "MNO" "PQR"
[2] etc, etc...
```

How do I add another string to the end of each lst member?

string s = "EndOfBlock";

```
[0] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "EndOfBlock"
[1] "JKL" "MNO" "PQR" "EndOfBlock"
[2] etc, etc...
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to add items use a `List<List<String>>/List(Of List(Of String))`. Arrays are fixed sized.

Comment: Sounds like you really want a List<List<string>>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commenters have noted, it sounds like you really want a `List<List<string>>`. But if you want to stick with a `List<string[]>`, here's how I'd expand each array.

```
List<string[]> list = ...
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    // copy to a local variable (list[i] is a property, which can't be passed 'ref')
    string[] array = list[i];

    // resize the local variable. (this creates a new string[] object)
    Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
    array[array.Length - 1] = "EndOfBlock";

    // put the new object back in the list, replacing the old smaller one.
    list[i] = array;
}
```

Comment: That answers the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Should be something like this:

```
var lst = new List<string[]>();
lst.Add(new string[] { "ABC", "DEF" });
lst.Add(new string[] { "GHI", "JKL" });

foreach (var item in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Length);
}

for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; ++i)
{
    var array = lst[i];
    Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);
    array[array.Length - 1] = "EndOfBlock";
    lst[i] = array;
}

foreach (var item in lst)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Length);
}
```

[`Array.Resize` Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx)

Comment: Array.Resize will create a new array and copy the elements to it. It won't put the new larger array back into the `List<>`.

Comment: "This method allocates a new array with the specified size, copies elements from the old array to the new one, and then replaces the old array with the new one." It's getting passed by reference, so it should update in the list as well.

Comment: Local variable `array` gets updated, but not the original List. No more than `array = null` would affect the list.

Comment: I take that back, @DavidYaw is 100% correct, this will not work.

Comment: @DavidYaw, fixed my code.  Thanks for that!  All that said, if I were user1481183, I would change my data type.  List<List<string>>, or something of the sort would be a lot nicer to use.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommand you use a `List<List<string>>`:

```
List<List<string>> lst = new List<List<string>>();
lst.ForEach(i=>i.Add("EndOfBlock"));
```

Comment: but I wouldn't reccomend using `List.ForEach`

Comment: I think using `List.ForEach` is better than using a `for` loop in this case, especially since there's only 1 instruction per iteration.

Comment: I'm struggling to justify my first comment so I think you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this with a `IList<string[]>` you can do this,

```
var lst = new List<string[]>
{
    { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" },
    { "JKL", "MNO", "PQR" },
    ...
}

var blockEnd = new string[] { "EndOfBlock" };

lst = lst.Select(a => 
    (a.Select(s => s).Concat(blockEnd))
    .ToArray()).ToList();
```

This would be much "nicer" if `lst` was a `Ilist<Ilist<string>>`.

```
var lst = new List<List<string>>
{
    { "ABC", "DEF", "GHI" },
    { "JKL", "MNO", "PQR" },
    ...
}

foreach(var row in lst)
{
   row.Add("EndOfBlock");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your list of arrays, you can do this:

```
List<string[]> lst = new List<string[]); //Where this is the poplated list instead of new;
for (ini i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
{
   List<string> tmpList = new List<string>(lst[i]);
   tmpList.Add("EndOfBlock");
   lst[i] = tmpList.ToArray();
}
```